# Cant select text, cant position caret in Firefox - Slatejs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, wysiwyg, slatejs

**Description**

Slatejs editor only in Firefox fails with text selection and caret positioning (by mouse). It always selects position before first character (path[0] offset[0]).
You can still use the keyboard to select text and position caret.

**Recording**

Firefox:
[image]

Chrome:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/UdH1xM7.gif]

**Expectation**

It should select text and position caret as it does in other browsers.

**Environment**

- Slate Version: 0.63.0
- Operating System: Windows 10
- Browser: Firefox 90.0.1 (64-bit)

**Editor implementation for reference**

```
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import { 
    BaseEditor, 
    createEditor, 
    Descendant, 
    Editor, 
    Element as SlateElement, 
    Node, 
    Text, 
    Transforms 
} from "slate";
import { Slate, Editable, ReactEditor, withReact } from "slate-react";
import { HistoryEditor, withHistory } from "slate-history";

export type CustomEditor = BaseEditor & ReactEditor & HistoryEditor

export type ParagraphElement = {
    type: 'paragraph'
    children: CustomText[]
}
  
export type TitleElement = {
    type: "title"
    children: CustomText[]
}

type CustomElement = ParagraphElement | TitleElement;
type FormattedText = { text: string, bold?: true };
type CustomText = FormattedText;


declare module "slate" {
    interface CustomTypes {
        Editor: CustomEditor
        Element: CustomElement
        Text: FormattedText
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////
// Custom helpers
////////////////////////////////////
const customEditor = {
    isBoldMarkActive(editor: CustomEditor) {
        const [match] = Editor.nodes(editor, {
          match: (n: any) => n.bold === true,
          universal: true,
        })
        return !!match
      },
      isTitleActive(editor: CustomEditor) {
        const [match] = Editor.nodes(editor, {
          match: (n: any) => n.type === "title",
        })
        return !!match
      },
      toggleBoldMark(editor: CustomEditor) {
        const isActive = customEditor.isBoldMarkActive(editor)
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          { bold: isActive ? undefined : true },
          { match: n => Text.isText(n), split: true }
        )
      },
      toggleTitle(editor: CustomEditor) {
        const isActive = customEditor.isTitleActive(editor)
        Transforms.setNodes(
          editor,
          { type: isActive ? undefined : "title" },
          { match: n => Editor.isBlock(editor, n) }
        )
      },
}
////////////////////////////////////
// Forced layout setup - title + paragraph
////////////////////////////////////
const withLayout = (editor: CustomEditor) => {
    const { normalizeNode } = editor
  
    editor.normalizeNode = ([node, path]) => {
      if (path.length === 0) {
        if (editor.children.length < 1) {
          const title: TitleElement = {
            type: "title",
            children: [{ text: 'Untitled' }],
          }
          Transforms.insertNodes(editor, title, { at: path.concat(0) })
        }
  
        if (editor.children.length < 2) {
          const paragraph: ParagraphElement = {
            type: 'paragraph',
            children: [{ text: '' }],
          }
          Transforms.insertNodes(editor, paragraph, { at: path.concat(1) })
        }
  
        for (const [child, childPath] of Node.children(editor, path)) {
          const type = childPath[0] === 0 ? "title" : 'paragraph'
  
          if (SlateElement.isElement(child) && child.type !== type) {
            const newProperties: Partial<SlateElement> = { type }
            Transforms.setNodes(editor, newProperties, { at: childPath })
          }
        }
      }
      return normalizeNode([node, path]);
    }
    return editor;
  }
////////////////////////////////////

const TextEditor = () => {
    const initialValue: Descendant[] = [
        { 
            type: 'title',
            children: [{ text: 'Enter a title...' }],
        },
        {
            type: 'paragraph',
            children: [{ text: 'Enter your question'}]
        }
    ];

    const editor = useMemo(() => withLayout(withHistory(withReact(createEditor()))), []);
    Transforms.deselect(editor);
    const [value, setValue] = useState<Descendant[]>(initialValue);

    const renderElement = useCallback((props) => <Element {...props} />, [])
    // Define a leaf rendering function that is memoized with `useCallback`.
    const renderLeaf = useCallback((props) => {
        return <Leaf {...props} />
    }, []);
    
    return (
        // Add the editable component inside the context.
        <Slate
            editor={editor}
            value={value}
            onChange={(value) => setValue(value)}
        >
            <div>
                <button
                  onMouseDown={event => {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    customEditor.toggleBoldMark(editor)
                  }}
                >
                  B
                </button>
                <button
                  onMouseDown={event => {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    customEditor.toggleTitle(editor)
                  }}
                >
                  H2
                </button>
            </div>
            <Editable
                renderElement={renderElement}
                autoFocus
                renderLeaf={renderLeaf}
            />
        </Slate>
    )
}

export default TextEditor

// Define a React component to render leaves with bold text.
const Leaf = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <span
      {...props.attributes}
      style={{ fontWeight: props.leaf.bold ? 'bold' : 'normal' }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </span>
  )
}

const Element = ({ attributes, children, element }: any) => {
    switch (element.type) {
        case 'title':
            return <h2 {...attributes}>{children}</h2>
        case 'paragraph':
            return <p {...attributes}>{children}</p>
        default:
            return <p {...attributes}>{children}</p>
    }
}
```

Any ideas what might have caused it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake. My CSS reset file contained: "user-select: none", which was somehow ignored by Chrome.